# Height of object set in percentage

Tags: html, css, height

[Trouble setting container as a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022000/trouble-setting-container-as-a-percentage)

Yes, I know, the parent of object has to have extremely set height in pixels.

It's a DIV and it's child of `<body>` and I really need to have it set with percent height.

Is there way to bypass it, except defining ultimate height in `<body>` by pixels?

Comment: define the `html, body {height:100%;}` then you can set the child div as a percentage of that: http://jsfiddle.net/58Mun/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the body height within the .css file to 100%.

Then set the containing elements to a percentage of that body height.